# Flexible Layout in CSS like vBulletin

Tags: css

When you resize [vBulletin](https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/forum.php) you can see the 3 columns rescaling nicely (Board Name, Threads / Posts, Last Post).

How could you achieve something like that in CSS? When I try to do so it always overlaps each other. The .board-icon width needs to stay the same because there's an image inside.

This is my CSS

```
.board-icon {
float: left;
width: 55px;
}

.board-title {
float: left;
background: red;
width: 50%;
}

.board-info {
float: left;
background: green;
width: 120px;
}

.board-lastpost {
float: left;
background: orange;
width: 240px;
}
```

Here are some other examples using the same flexible layout:

- http://punbb.informer.com/forums/
- http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php
- http://community.invisionpower.com/

Answer (score 0):

The CSS behind it isn't that complex for modern browsers. Though some of these techniques will not work in earlier versions of ie without some modifications.

Using this HTML

```
<body>

    <div id="canvas">

        ...

    </div>

</body>
```

And this CSS

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}

#canvas, .main-width {
    min-width:960px;
    width: 80%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.clear, #canvas:after {
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;

#canvas:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
}
```

Start working with % widths, not px widths as you have in your example. The only time to use fixed width values should be on a min-width delcaration.

You could create two fluid columns inside your canvas div for example

```
<div class="col1>

    ...

</div>

<div class="col2">

    ...

</div>

<br class="clear" />
```

And the CSS (no need for min-widths now as 34% of 960px is just as good)

```
.col1,.col2 {
    float:left;

}

.col1 {
    width:34%;
}

.col2 {
    width:66%;
}
```

Notice the `.main-width` declaration above? That applies the `#canvas` style to any container in the #canvas div, giving it exactly the same width and fluidity.

```
<div class="main-width"> ... </div>
```

That should set you on the right tracks, just remember that you need to work in % not px. If you need to use borders on elements, make sure they are `display:block` to maintain positioning with % widths.